# Implement a source code that turns numbers into text (C++)

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++ a while back. I am reading Jumping into C++ .
The problem pertains to chapter 7, question 1:

> Implement a source code that turns numbers into text.

This is what I have done so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int LessThen20 (int i);

int main () {
    int i = 1;
    cout << "please input a number: \n";
    cin >> i;
    if (i < 20) {
        cout << LessThen20(i);
    }

    if ( i >= 20 && i < 30) {
        cout <<"Twenty " ??
    }
}

int LessThen20 (int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        cout << "zero" <<endl;
    }

    if ( i == 1) {
        cout << "one"; <<endl;
    }

    if (i == 2) {
        cout << "two"; <<endl;
    }

    if ( i == 3) {
        cout << "three"; <<endl;
    }

    if (i == 4) {
        cout << "four"; <<endl;
    }

    if ( i == 5) {
        cout << "five"; <<endl;
    }

    if (i == 6) {
        cout << "six"; <<endl;
    }

    if ( i == 7) {
        cout << "seven"; <<endl;
    }

    if (i == 8) {
        cout << "eight" <<endl;
    }

    if ( i == 9) {
        cout << "nine"; <<endl;
    }

    if (i == 10) {
        cout << "ten"; <<endl;
    }

    if ( i == 11) {
        cout << "eleven"; <<endl;
    }

    if (i == 12) {
        cout << "twelve"; <<endl;
    }

    if ( i == 13) {
        cout << "thirteen"; <<endl;
    }

    if (i == 14) {
        cout << "fourteen"; <<endl;
    }

    if ( i == 15) {
        cout << "fifteen"; <<endl;
    }

    if (i == 16) {
        cout << "sixteen"; <<endl;
    }

    if ( i == 17) {
        cout << "seventeen"; <<endl;
    }

    if (i == 18) {
        cout << "eighteen"; <<endl;
    }

    if ( i == 19) {
        cout << "nineteen"; <<endl;
    }
}
```

My program works as long as the number inputted is less then 20. But I dont know how I could turn the number 25, into "twenty five".

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `std::map` is a great asset. Also strive to find patterns and when you find one, separate it. For example, 13-19 have a prefix and then "teen". That means you don't have to repeat "teen" for each one.

Comment: 1. Google for "switch statement". 2. Use map and string concatenation. This should be enough to move further.

Comment: This program is really structured wrong, that should at least be a switch statement, not a bunch of `if`s.  At least have the decency to use proper naming conventions for your functions, and make the function `return` the result, instead of outputting it directly.

Comment: @AJMansfield brings up another good point. Your function says it returns an `int`, but returns nothing. That's undefined behaviour and if your compiler doesn't warn you, it's time to turn up the warning level.

Comment: You can do it all 'in the cloud' by using the Wolfram|Alpha API to get you the answer.  You just send it the number, and fetch the value from the "Number Name" pod.  Other online services could do this perhaps even better, but Wolfram|Alpha was the first one to come to mind.

Comment: Its not less "then", its actually less "than".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything below twenty is a special case. However, instead of having a huge if chain, you should have a data structure containing `"zero", "one", "two",` etc and index into the data structure. (Vector, map or array for example. If you don't know how to use any of these, I suggest you learn because data structures are VERY useful in all programming languages and you will want to learn them).

Above twenty, we have to start coding more generically. We have to split creating the word version into parts:

1) Getting the units column. You can use number % 10 to get only the units, because % 10 gets the remainder after dividing by 10. You can use the units number to index into your zero, one, two etc data structure from earlier and get what to print.

2) Getting the tens column. Similar idea - (number / 10) % 10. Now index tens column into a data structure like "", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", ... at 0, 1, 2, 3...

3) ... And so on for every higher column.

Comment: I'm almost (but not quite) sure that there is a better way to get the next digit than `number / 10 % 10`.

Comment: @AJMansfield Not really, unless you mean using itoa to turn it into a character array and inspecting the character array.

Comment: @AJMansfield if you really want to try an eke all all the performance, you can keep an int as the running power of ten, incurring a multiplication for every digit place, and then just doing the division. Additionally, the powers of ten could be precomputed, removing even that cost in exchange for some memory overhead.

Answer (score 4):

If the second digit is greater than 2, you just have to concatenate the same way you are with "twenty" but with thirty, forty, etc.

The same approach can be applied to the hundreds, thousands, etc.

It would probably be best if you stored the "prefixes" in an array of some kind that can be directly indexed (i.e. so that myTensArray[3] gives "thirty" for example).

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions but since I think you want to implement it yourself here a few ideas (for integer types only):
First i would determine the length of the char array needed to store your string. The number of digits can be determined by

```
int digits = ((int)log10(number))+1; //+1 if number is negative
```

next you want to split your number into digits

```
for(int i = digits - 1; number; i--){  //until number is 0
//charFromDidgit(...) returns the char for a nuber between 0 and 9 (e.g. '3' for 3) 
yourCharArray[i] = charFromDigit(number%10);
number /= 10;
}
```

Dont forget do append the terminating 0 at the end of the array

Comment: I'm pretty sure logs don't work on negative numbers.  (At least not the function you are calling)

Comment: bool negative = number < 0;
if (negative)
number = -number;
to be absolutely sure nothing goes wrong you could use a unsigned type since the negative signed part is 1 bigger than the positive:
bool negative = number < 0; unsigned int absVal = negative ? -number : number;

Answer (score -1):

If you want a way to do this with only primitive concepts, you can simply use a loop that checks if the number is over a certain value and then subtracts from that number depending on how large it is. After each run of the loop, use a variable to hold the amount of times you've subtracted from the number.

For instance:

```
//Your number is greater than 1 billion
while ( x > 1000000000 ) { 
billions += 1 
x -= 1000000000 
}

//Your number is greater than 1 million
while ( x > 1000000 ) { 
millions += 1 
x -= 1000000
}

//Your number is greater than 1 thousand
while ( x > 1000 ) { 
thousands += 1 
x -= 1000
}
```

And so on. Then you've made this into a much smaller problem, since you only have to deal with three-digit numbers now (where you can use the exact same steps above, just with tens and hundreds). You can also use the modulus operator. It's more efficient, though harder to implement.